# Grid deselects when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, datatable, datagrid, colorize

I have created a simple data grid with dummy data according to [this example](https://www.datagridxl.com/demos/colorize-cells). However, if I click one of the custom buttons, the grid deselects and the method (_setCellColors) is never called.

When I add a playground grid in the API and perform the "_setCellColors" method, it works fine however. (https://www.datagridxl.com/api/methods).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. How to call the methods without deselecting the grid?

[image]

Edit: forgot to include the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/0nrjvx1p/5/.

```
var grid = new DataGridXL("grid", {
  data: DataGridXL.createDummyData(100,10)
});

// not working
document.getElementById("button-pink").onclick = function(){
  grid._setCellColors(grid.getCellSelection(), "#ffe1f0");
}

// not working
document.getElementById("button-green").onclick = function(){
  grid._setCellColors(grid.getCellSelection(), "#f0ffe1");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found the issue. It was actually on the demo page, but I overlooked it somehow.

If anyone else is looking for the answer: the buttons do not automatically belong to the app, unless you add a CSS classname to the buttons, or their parent:

```
.dgxl-app
```

Just add the class to your parent div:

```
<div class="dgxl-app">
    <button class="button" id="button-green">Green</button>
    <button class="button" id="button-pink">Pink</button>
</div>
```

Here's the updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8tqyhab/